# When I use php to get the value of a select list using the post method sometimes the value doesn't fully show up

Tags: php, post, echo

When I use the post method and php to process a simple form, I try to echo the select list option and it doesn't all show up for instance one of my options is video card $200 and when it echos on card $200 shows up on the page.
Here is the select list:

```
 <select name="hardware">
 <option>&nbsp;</option>
 <option>Monitor $100</option>
 <option>Mother Board $250</option>
 <option>Video Card $200</option>
 <option>Keyboard $300</option>
 </select>
```

and here is the php code

```
<?php
$parts=$_POST['hardware'];
$partsQuantity=$_POST['hquantity'];
$software=$_POST['software'];
$softwareQuantity=$_POST['squantity'];
echo "".$parts." ".$partsQuantity."<br>".$software." ".$softwareQuantity."<br>";
?>
```

when I choose video card $200 and echo it only card $200 shows up

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` show?

Comment: I don't have an explanation, but this is poor design anyway. You should use the `value` attribute in the `option` tag, rather than using the text. You can then give them small integer or keyword values, which you can look up in a database or associative array to get the details.

Comment: It shows ['hardware']=> Video Card $200

Comment: I don't see any way that the word `Video` could disappear from the output.

Comment: Does it work correctly with `Mother Board $250`?

Comment: Yes it works with mother board.I added the <code>value="Video Card $200"</code> and it still only echos <code>card $200</code> but if I echo it twice for some reason it shows the full value. For instance if I use var_dump It shows in the var_dump output and where it was supposed to echo.

Comment: I suspect something in your CSS and other elements around this is overlapping it. Do you see `Video` in the DOM inspector?

Comment: Yes it's in the DOM as the full value

Comment: It's something in the CSS thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the form is submitted, the value of $_POST['hardware'] will be the value of the option you selected in the hardware select, not a list of the values of all of the different options contained in the select. Also, your option tags are all missing the value attribute.

Comment: Where did you get the impression he expects it to be all the different options. He's just saying that when he selects the `Video Card $200` option, he's only seeing `Card $200` in the output. And if you leave out the `value` attribute, it defaults to the text of the option.